# Max chars on single HTML line

Tags: html

I have a JUnit Report who generate me a html report.
My JUnit Report generate a huge html line ... arround 1 millions chars.
My page terminated suddenly.
There is a limit for html code for single line?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such limit. More likely your browser timed out, because rendering such a huge file took too much time.